# How to enhance the performance of naive CMDS?

Tags: binary-data, multidimensional-scaling

I'm performing Classical MDS on the distance over columns of binary matrix. The result is like this:

[image]

The points lies on two lines vertical to each other. I don't think useful information is shown in this MDS chart. So I'm looking forward to the ways to enhance the classical MDS perfromance.

The data source is a 100 * 600, {0,1} valued matrix. I use normalized euclidean matrix between columns.

```
dist(col1, col2) = EuclideanDist(col1, col2) / sqrt(Norm2(col1)*Norm2(col2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the upvote but any comment could be more appreciated.

Comment: 1) The map itself does not leave an impression that the results are degenerated (oversimplified), but you should try 3d solution, for sure. 2) What is the stress value and what type of stress yo use; how the distances X disparities plot look like? 3) Euclidean distance usually isn't quite informative for binary data; are you willing to pick up a better (for your specific investigation) proximity measure. 4) If that was metric MDS, try nonmetric.

Comment: And what is "naive" CMDS by the way?